# When using splncs.bst style from Springer lncs template, Bibtex does not compile well doi fields that contains "_"

Tags: bibtex, lncs, doi

I am using `BibTeX`. When my bib file contains a reference with a `doi` field like this one:

```
Doi = {10.1007/978-94-007-2421_10}
```

it does not compile. I think `BibTeX` thinks that `_` is a math symbol. 
But when I cut this symbol it compiles fine.

```
Doi = {10.1007/978-94-007-2421}
```

Here is a MWE:

```
\Documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[hyphens,spaces]{url}
\urlstyle{rm}
\usepackage[colorlinks,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\title{My Title}
\author{My Name}
\maketitle

Foo bar baz \cite{maggino2012a}.

\bibliographystyle{splncs04}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{maggino2012a,
    Author = {Maggino, Filomena and Zumbo, Bruno D},
    Booktitle = {Handbook of social indicators and quality of life research},
    Doi = {10.1007/978-94-007-2421-1_10},
    Editor = {Land K., Michalos A., Sirgy M.},
    Pages = {201--238},
    Publisher = {Springer, Dordrecht},
    Title = {Measuring the quality of life and the construction of social indicators},
    Year = {2012},
  }
\end{filecontents*}

\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `Doi = {10.1007/978-94-007-2421\_10}`?

Comment: Yes. It results. But it's a pity that I have to modify my bib file for doing this.

Comment: Which bibliography style do you employ?

Comment: _Maybe_ it would work if you could made underscore a letter before bibliography starts? Like this: `\catcode\`\_11\relax`

Comment: I am using `splncs04` style from Springer `LLNCS`. Sorry Andreas but I don't understand your comment. Where should I put `catcode _11\relax`?

Comment: With the `splncs04` bibliography style, it's necessary to load the `url` and/or `hyperref` packages in order for BibTeX not to interpret the `_` (underscore) character inside `doi` and `url` fields as the token that initiates subscripts in math mode. Hence, be sure to write something like `\usepackage[hyphens,spaces]{url}` in the preamble of your document.

Comment: @Mico Latex Error: Option clash for package `url`?

Comment: Please tell us how you're loading the `url` package at the moment.

Comment: ```\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref,xcolor}
\renewcommand\UrlFont{\color{blue}\rmfamily}
\usepackage[hyphens,spaces]{url}```

Comment: The `hyperref` package must *always* be loaded *after* the `url` package -- and *after* the `xcolor` package too, for that matter. No exceptions, unless you want to waste lots of time interpreting cryptic error messages. Hence, run the following instructions instead: `\usepackage{xcolor} \usepackage[hyphens,spaces]{url} \urlstyle{rm} \usepackage[colorlinks,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}`.

Comment: Lots of warnings and an error: ```Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ﬂ (U+FB02) (inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX.```

Comment: @sbac - Ok, the subject of your latest comment -- `Unicode character ﬂ (U+FB02)` -- is utterly unrelated to the topic of your query, which was the presence of underscore characters in a `doi` field. If you want to find out how to fix the new issue, I suggest you post a *new*, focused query. And do please familiarize yourself with how to post an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) (minimum working example) that generates the issue you would like to fix. Posting an MWE greatly increases the odds of someone being able to come up with a diagnosis and, better still, a cure.

Comment: OK I'll do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have run into the same problem, with another BibTeX style. In the .bst file, replace the function `format.doi` by the following code, which escapes `_` characters (also `%` and `^`) and allows line breaks at relevant points in the DOI.

```
INTEGERS { l }
% the real length of a string (text.length$ doesn't count some special characters)
FUNCTION {string.length}
{ #1 'l :=
  {duplicate$ duplicate$ #1 l substring$ = not}
  {l #1 + 'l :=}
  while$
  pop$ l
}

STRINGS{replace find text}
INTEGERS{find_length}

% usage: <string> "~" "tilde" find.replace
FUNCTION{find.replace}
{ 'replace :=
  'find :=
  'text :=
  find string.length 'find_length :=
  ""
    { text empty$ not }
    { text #1 find_length substring$ find =
        {
          replace *
          text #1 find_length + global.max$ substring$ 'text :=
        }
        { text #1 #1 substring$ *
          text #2 global.max$ substring$ 'text :=
        }
      if$
    }
  while$
}

% allow line breaks when formatting a DOI
FUNCTION {allowbreaks.doi}
{
  "_" "\_\allowbreak{}" find.replace
  "^" "\^" find.replace
  "%" "\%" find.replace
  "/" "/\allowbreak{}" find.replace
  "-" "-\allowbreak{}" find.replace
}

FUNCTION {format.doi}
{ doi empty$
    { "" }
    { "\MyDOI{https://doi.org/" doi * "}{" * doi allowbreaks.doi * "}" * }
  if$
}
```

You'll also need to provide a definition for \MyDOI in your LaTeX file such as that below, or replace it by \doi

```
\newcommand{\MyDOI}[2]{\BeginAccSupp{E=Digital Object Identifier}\textsc{DOI}\EndAccSupp{}: \href{#1}{#2}}
```

Comment: I have changed `splncs04.bst` as you wrote and I have got the following error: ```ERROR: Undefined control sequence.

--- TeX said ---
\MyDOI #1#2->\BeginAccSupp 
                           {E=Digital Object Identifier}\textsc {DOI}\EndAcc...l.11 ...eak{}2421-\allowbreak{}1\_\allowbreak{}10}```

Comment: You will need to `\usepackage{accsupp}` in the document preamble.

Answer (score 8):

(I've updated this answer to reflect the fact that Springer has recently updated the `llncs` document class to version 2.21. The upshot is that it's no longer necessary to define a replacement for the `\doi` macro.)

Here's how to make your MWE work so that doi strings that contain TeX-special characters don't make LaTeX choke. Observe that I've also changed the `editor` field from `Editor = {Land K., Michalos A., Sirgy M.},` to `Editor = {Land, K. and Michalos, A. and Sirgy, M.},`. In `author` and `editor` fields, please use the keyword `and` to separate authors. I would also separate the information currently contained in the `publisher` field into separate `publisher` and `address` fields.

[image]

```
\documentclass{llncs}  % to be used with v. 2.21 (or later) of 'llncs' class

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@incollection{maggino2012a,
    Author    = {Maggino, Filomena and Zumbo, Bruno D.},
    Booktitle = {Handbook of Social Indicators and 
                 Quality of Life Research},
    Doi       = {10.1007/978-94-007-2421-1_10},
    Editor    = {Land, K. and Michalos, A. and Sirgy, M.},
    Pages     = {201--238},
    Publisher = {Springer},
    Address   = {Dordrecht},
    Title     = {Measuring the quality of life and the 
                 construction of social indicators},
    Year      = {2012},
  }
\end{filecontents}
\bibliographystyle{splncs04}

\usepackage{iftex}
\ifpdftex
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\fi

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xurl} % allow line breaks anywhere in a URL string
\urlstyle{same    % optional
\usepackage[colorlinks,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\cite{maggino2012a}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: My knowledge is not enough to create a definition of "\doi" that includes the symbol "_".

Comment: @sbac - Please see the addendum I posted a couple of minutes ago.

Comment: I have run exactly your file and: ```ERROR: Missing $ inserted.

--- TeX said ---
<inserted text> 
                $
l.10 ...(2012). \doi{10.1007/978-94-007-2421-1_10}```

Comment: @sbac - I don't know what to tell you at this point. The screenshot I posted above is what I got from running the code that's shown above. Did you delete all aux files before running the code above?

Comment: Yes I deleted all aux files before running. I tried running in `Emacs`, `TeXStudio` and `TeXShop` with the same result: it only works if I change `_`. Should I have to change the `doi` definition in the style file before?

Comment: @sbac - Emacs, TeXstudio, and TeXshop are all front-ends to a TeX distribution, but *not* TeX distributions themselves. Which TeX distribution is installed on your computer? And do please state from where you got your copy of the bibliography style file? (Not all repositories of Springer bib style files have the same files...)

Comment: `TeXLive-2018` on a MacBook Pro.

Comment: I have a MacBook Pro as well, and I run MacTeX2018. The screenshot I posted above was generated by the code I posted above. I just tried the code shown above again, and it still runs fine. If you can't get my code to compile, there's something going on that I don't know about and hence can't address. I'm afraid I just can't help you any further at this stage. Do you maybe want me to delete this answer, as it is evidently of no use to you?

Comment: No, I can try later on Windows or OverLeaf. And it can help other people with the same problem.

Comment: It also doesn't run on `OverLeaf` for the same reason.

Comment: @sbac - I guess you've established by now that there's something in your document, rather than something in any given TeX distribution, that's causing the problem. Since the MWE I posted above runs just fine on my system, all I can surmise is that something bad happened when you copied and pasted the MWE code into your own document. Unfortunately, my psychic abilities are utterly worthless, so I won't bother with speculating what exactly the "something bad" might be.

Comment: Maybe we could overcome this problem if you could send me your `tex` file because visually, I can't notice any difference between the file that I use and yours.

Comment: The suggested code is also not working for me with the same error as sbac is getting.

Comment: I wonder what the correct fix to the bst file is, though.